# Error scheduling email send definition

Tags: email, marketing-cloud

Prospect is testing ET's API and trying to schedule an email send definition using this method: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/scheduling_a_user_initiated_email_message_send_via_the_web_service_api/

Getting this error:

> Error Code ::: 2 Status Code ::: Error Status Message ::: Exception
>   occurred during [ScheduleEmailSendDefinition] ErrorID: 240278779

Any idea what that might be and how they could fix?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the reason was the account had sending privileges disabled. Problem resolved. Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ErrorID, it looks like the email has validation issues so it isn't able to send.  For detailed information on the validation issues, go into the ExactTarget Email interface, find the email, then use the Validate option.